# Use existing JS "package" with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have some existing JS code which I am releasing as an NPM package. Let's call it "my-pkg". I've created the `package.json` and installed my new local package. My package consists of these files:

- my-pkg.js
- package.json

**my-pkg.js**

```
function ping() {
    console.log("Hi!");
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-pkg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My test package.",
  "main": "my-pkg.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I try to use my package like this:

```
npm install .\my-pkg
node
> var myPkg = require("my-pkg");
undefined
> myPkg.ping();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Note that this is on Windows 8 in an elevated command line with Node.JS v0.12.2. I am looking to expose existing JS functionality, not write a brand new NPM package. What am I missing here?

Comment: Show us some code. What do you have in `my-pkg.js`?

Comment: @E_net4 Too quick - just added code. :)

Comment: Writing a "brand new NPM package" literally takes a minute. You've basically done it by accident here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All [Node.js modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) must export its contents via `module.exports`. You lack the following in your file:

```
module.exports.ping = ping;
```

This works as well (`exports` is initially assigned to `module.exports`):

```
exports.ping = ping;
```

Comment: This has to be done for every exposed function, then? Can't just simply expose the contents of the "main" JS as-is? I'd have to add an `index.js` and it would simply wrap/point to the existing JS functions in my library, is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: @JoshM. The whole point of `module.exports` is to control what's exposed and what's private. By default everything is private. There's no way to "export all", but you can declare all your functions in the context of an export if you prefer: `module.exports = { ping: function() { ...  } }`.

Comment: It's the beauty of the Node.js module system. Everything you declare in a module is private unless you either export it or make it a global (which I _do not_ recommend).

Comment: My library already handles what should be public/private, so I would only be exposing functions which are already public. That's why it seems redundant to me to wrap/point to functions which I've already determined to be "public", but I'm new to Node.JS so bare with me. I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshM. I'd say it's much easier if you rely on Node's module system rather than making your own workarounds to attain encapsulation at this level.

Comment: Not planning on doing any workarounds, just wanted to know the proper way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @E_net4 I created an `index.js` and set my package to point to it as `main`. I added `exports.ping = ping` and also tried `exports.ping = module.ping` but neither work. How do I expose my `ping` function in `my-pkg.js`?

Comment: You must export things in the same file they are declared. In "index.js", simply `require` the remaining files to retrieve their contents ( `ping = require('./someothermodule').ping` ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77829/discussion-between-josh-m-and-e-net4).